# Не указывать количество в каждом товаре (OpenCart)

Tags: администрирование, opencart, веб-программирование

Добрый день! Не могу понять... Когда добавляю товар, всегда нужно указывать количество ( по умолчанию 1 )? Хотелось бы сделать что бы количество было неограниченным во всех товарах. Или нужно вручную при добавлении каждого товара ставить 99999?

Comment: вы о чем вообще? и какое отношение все эти ваши товары имеют к программированию?

Comment: Никакого. Для этого и указал теги

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Админка - Система - Настройки - Атрибуты -

Заказ при нехватке на складе: Да

Предупреждать о нехватке на складе: Нет

Решение не моё. Взял [отсюда](http://opencartforum.ru/topic/1914-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0/).

Comment: То что я искал. Спасибо большое